# ResteasyClient returns "xxx.yyy.net:443 failed to respond" on some systems

Tags: java, resteasy, apache-httpclient-4.x

The following code works on some systems, including my development system, but fails on `request.get()` on other systems (All either Win 7 or Win Server 2008).

```
@Provider
public static class ClientRequestFilter implements javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestFilter {
    private Cookie cookie;

    public ClientRequestFilter(Cookie cookie) {
        super();
        this.cookie = cookie;
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext clientRequestContext) throws IOException {
        if (this.cookie!=null) {
            List<Object> cookies = new ArrayList<>();
            cookies.add(this.cookie);
            clientRequestContext.getHeaders().put("Cookie", cookies);
        }
    }
}
      :
      :
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
    .register(new ClientRequestFilter(authorizationToken))
    .disableTrustManager()
    .establishConnectionTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .socketTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("https://xxx.yyy.net");
Builder request = target.request();
if (!OrganizationId.isEmpty())request.header("Organization-Id", OrganizationId);

Response response = request.get();
```

On the systems where `request.get()` fails, the call is a very simple call to check that the target is running and should return a short text status. The same call works from the browser.

The stack trace shows that I appear to get no response from the target. I tried turning off the firewall and anti-virus, in case they were interfering.

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to invoke request
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:287)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:407)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.get(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:159)
        at com.hp.pcDataCollector.DCRest.action(DCRest.java:138)
        at com.hp.pcDataCollector.DCRest.get(DCRest.java:59)
        at com.hp.pcDataCollector.DCaaa.checkConnection(DCaaa.java:154)
        at com.hp.pcDataCollector.DCaaa.loginToGenesis(DCaaa.java:125)
        at com.hp.pcDataCollector.DataCollector.run(DataCollector.java:118)
        at com.hp.pcDataCollector.DataCollector.main(DataCollector.java:77)
Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: xxx.yyy.net:443 failed to respond
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java
    )
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.j
    197)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:283)
        ... 8 more
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the `com.hp.pcDataCollector` package? What functional role does  it play in the request you are sending? Is it something you expected to be a part of the processing chain?

Comment: @SeanMickey That is my app. The call to `.get()` is in from my method `com.hp.pcDataCollector.DCRest.action()`